# Call to undefined function form_open() in CI 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I am using CodeIgniter 4 and loading form helper in the following way, but it still says,

> Call to undefined function form_open()

In BaseController.php i am autoloading **form helper**.

```
protected $helpers = ["form"];
```

**Route:**

```
$routes->get('admin/login', 'admin\LoginController::index');
```

**Controller:**

```
public function index()
{
    
    echo view('admin/login');
}
```

**View:**

```
<?php echo form_open('admin/dologin');?>
    <?= csrf_token() ?>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <div class="input-group-text">
          <span class="fas fa-envelope"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <div class="input-group-text">
          <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign In</button>
      </div>
      <!-- /.col -->
    </div>
  <?php echo form_close();?>
```

**How can i get rid of from this error?**

```
Call to undefined function form_open()
```

Comment: Check the Quotes. `"`

Comment: @AbdullaNilam `protected $helpers = ['form'];` with single quote it is not working

Comment: `helper("form");` try inside the function

Comment: @AbdullaNilam it works, then what is the benefit for autoload in `BaseController.php` if we have to add in each function ?

Comment: True.  Something wrong in the project may b. wanted to make sure `helper("form");` works or not. Restart the application and check

Comment: I restarted my local server several times. it is showing same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246689/discussion-between-hamza-zafeer-and-abdulla-nilam).

Answer (score 2):

[Loading this Helper](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#loading-this-helper)

> This helper is loaded using the following code:

> ```php
> <?php
>
> helper('form');
> ```

In your `app/Controllers/BaseController.php` file,

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

// ...

class BaseController extends Controller
{
    public function initController(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        // Do Not Edit This Line
        parent::initController($request, $response, $logger);

        // Preload any models, libraries, etc, here.
        helper("form");
    }
}
```

Comment: then what is the purpose of `protected $helpers =` ??

Comment: @AbdullaNilam Did it work for you?

Comment: `$helpers` works for me. Not in his. [check the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73089822/call-to-undefined-function-form-open-in-ci-4/73091856?noredirect=1#comment129088096_73089822) and below comments too

Comment: @AbdullaNilam I meant the solution in my answer.

Comment: [He Cleary said `helper("form");` works for him](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73089822/call-to-undefined-function-form-open-in-ci-4/73091856?noredirect=1#comment129088086_73089822).  Read the Question. The issue is `protected $helpers`

Comment: Even if you load it in your `__construct`, it doesn't matter. Hope you got the point

Comment: @AbdullaNilam `protected $helpers = ...` should be sufficient. I only provided the above solution as an *alternative* since the OP seems not to know where in the `BaseController` to load the `form` helper using the global `helper(...)` function.

Comment: inside constructor I did